# Django Class based views for DELETE method cannot redirect to ListView

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, http-delete, htmx

I'm using django 3.1 and class based views.

When I send a request that is METHOD_OVERRIDE with DELETE and using POST, it is correctly sent to the delete view I setup.

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name="dispatch")
class ServerDetail(DeleteView):
    # form_class = ServerCreateForm
    model = Server
    # template_name = "core/server/create.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("servers-list")

    def get_success_url(self):
        if self.success_url:
            return self.success_url
        else:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured("No URL to redirect to. Provide a success_url.")

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = self.request.user
        social_token = SocialToken.objects.filter(
            account__user=user, account__provider="digitalocean"
        ).first()
        
        droplet_id = kwargs["pk"]
        droplet = digitalocean.Droplet(id=droplet_id, token=social_token.token)

        droplet.destroy()

        success_url = self.get_success_url()

        return redirect(success_url)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

But it will fail as at the redirect to /servers/ there will be a 405 Method Not Allowed error.

The request was sent as X-HTTP-Method-Override set to DELETE in a POST request to `/servers/:id/`.

The deletion happened successfully, the issue is at the redirection after the successful delete.

### what it looks like in the console

```
[10/Jan/2021 14:58:30] "GET /servers/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4105
[10/Jan/2021 14:58:36] "DELETE /servers/12345 HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[10/Jan/2021 14:59:15] "DELETE /servers/12345/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
Method Not Allowed (DELETE): /servers/
Method Not Allowed: /servers/
[10/Jan/2021 14:59:15] "DELETE /servers/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0
```

### what works as workaround

However, if I sent a regular POST method to `/servers/:id/delete` and setup the urls accordingly, the redirection is fine.

So basically I cannot use DELETE when I used class based views yes?

### Update

Apparently this is because the client reuses the same DELETE method for the 302. Hence now adding htmx as tag to the question

Comment: How did you make the DELETE request?

Comment: X-HTTP-Method-Override set to DELETE in a POST request to `/servers/:id/`

Comment: I like your antipatterns website  by the way 

Comment: what method arrives in the "console". Can you see a DELETE request (normally a class-based view *can* handle a DELETE request), so I'm trying to find out what the problem is.

Comment: can you refresh the question? I have pasted what I saw in the console. Not sure if that's what you are referring to. there is some delay in the request because i was running ipdb to check if the delete method was really called

Comment: Hmmm... but it looks like you made a DELETE request to `servers/12345/` which worked (returns a 302, so redirect), and then you make a DELETE request to `/servers/` itself, but likely that is a `ListView` that did not implement a `delete` method (well it would be a bit "odd" to delete the entire list of servers I think).

Comment: So it looks as if your client follows the redirect, but with the same headers, and thus again makes a DELETE request to the view where it was redirected to.

Comment: are you saying this is a client issue? My client is doing nothing special other than sending a POST request to `/servers/:id/ ` with the header X-HTTP-Method-Override set to DELETE

Comment: yes, but based on the console that DELETE request works fine, it returns a 302 response. But what happens next is that your client makes again a DELETE request, but now to `/servers` (likely due to the redirect), but normally a redirect is done with a GET request, not a delete request. So a possible reason is that the client again makes a request (a GET request), but still with the `X-HTTP-Method-Override` to `DELETE`, so this is again turned into a `DELETE` request.

Comment: oh I see, so it's indeed a client issue. Okay thank you

Comment: Thank you @WillemVanOnsem I will ask the maintainer of the client library for help